# How to build docker images using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Let say I have a docker hub repository `my_registry/project_name_service1`.

I would like to build my docker images with the following repository name `my_registry/project_name_service1`

e.g docker-compose.yml

```
service1:
  image: my_registry/project_name_service1
```

when I build the images using docker-compose build service1

the repository name becomes `project_name_service1`

where the prefix project_name is set in .env file `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=project_name`

Now

how can I get `my_registry/project_name_service1` as repository name for the docker image when I use `docker-compose build service1`

so that I can use `docker-compose push service1` to push the image to the docker registry (say docker hub)

Answer (score 0):

Provide container name value to your docker image with `container_name : my_registry/project_name_service`

See this documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#container_name

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making a bit of a confusion regarding the terms.
You have images and you have containers. Each of them have names.
An image name is `<repository>/<image_tag>:<image_version>`.
A container name can be anything.
When you pull or push images, the  part decides from which or to which repository to pull or push.

In docker-compose.yml you define your services.

If you only define "image" for a service, but no build context, then nothing will be build. The image will be downloaded when you run "docker-compose up"

If you define a build context ("build"), then docker-compose will build an image based on that context and then tag it with the name you specify in "image".

COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME is used by "docker-compose up" to name the containers, not the images.

You can also re-tag an image with a docker command if you need it.

I hope this clarifies a bit more and you understand how to configure your docker-compose file. If you still have issues drop me a comment.

Comment: how can I build images with the repository name of the following format: `registry_name/repository_name` or `registry_name/some_name`

Comment: Fill in image in the service with whatever value you need. When you build it that is the name that will be used to tag the image

Comment: It worked. I was using two separate docker-compose files. docker-compose.yml and production-docker-compose.yml. So, on every build, it was taking the default docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: Good to hear. You should consider using docker-compose.override.yml for that. It let's you easily overwrite parts of the configuration.